# Ionic 3 Angular 5 post data HttpClient

Tags: angular, web-services, post, ionic-framework, httpclient

I'm trying to make a data post in a local webservice but I can't do it in the enterprise :P
Anyway this is the code I tried to write:

in the provider (src/providers/team-data/team-data.ts)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TeamDataProvider {

  apiUrlGet="http://localhost/MyWebService/api/getteams.php";
  apiUrlAdd="http://localhost/MyWebService/api/createteam.php";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello TeamDataProvider Provider');
  }

  getTeams(): Observable<any[]> {    
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrlGet).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );    
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const err = error || '';
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  getRemoteData(){
    this.http.get(this.apiUrlGet).map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    });
  }

  addTeam(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.apiUrlAdd, JSON.stringify(data))
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res);
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

}
```

in addteam.ts

```
import { TeamDataProvider } from './../../providers/team-data/team-data';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the AddteamPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-addteam',
  templateUrl: 'addteam.html',
})
export class AddteamPage {

  teams = {
      name: '',
      member: ''
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public teamDataProvider: TeamDataProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AddteamPage');
  }

  saveTeam() {
    this.teamDataProvider.addTeam(this.teams).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

and in addteam.html

```
<!--
  Generated template for the AddteamPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-title>addteam</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Add User</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="saveTeam()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>TeamName</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="teams.name" name="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>TeamMember</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="teams.member" name="member"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> 
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Team</button>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

When I start the app and, after filling in the fields, I press the button to add the fields in my db, in console this error appears:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost/MyWebService/api/createteam.php", ok: false, …}
error
:
error
:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:73072:51) at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5114:33) at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581) at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834) at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16794) at p (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27648) at XMLHttpRequest.v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893)
message
:
"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
stack
:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:73072:51)↵    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5114:33)↵   at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)↵    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)↵    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16794)↵    at p (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27648)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893)"
__proto__
:
Error
text
:
"<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyWebService/api/createteam.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />↵<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: member in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/MyWebService/api/createteam.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />↵{"error":true,"message":"Could not add team"}"
__proto__
:
Object
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost/MyWebService/api/createteam.php"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
url
:
"http://localhost/MyWebService/api/createteam.php"
__proto__
:
HttpResponseBase
```

When instead I try to make a post request with Postman,
inserting the right url as POST,
and inserting in body -> form-data,
the key: name and member, and after filling and sending the request, in body -> Pretty appears the message "{" error ": false," message ":" Team added successfully "}" and the fields are actually added in the database.

what am I doing wrong? how should I do to make it work?
thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling with similar issue couple of days back. At last I converted data object for FormData. Saving FormData instead of json solve my problem.

```
addTeam(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.apiUrlAdd, this.getFormData(data))
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res);
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
        getFormData(object) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(key, object[key]));
            return formData;
        }
```

Comment: why use promise? Just curious. I saw it somewhere else too.

Comment: Promise is standard for asynchronous processing in JavaScript these days. You and use resolve and reject to identify the process output. and one important point, you can catch those promises with then.

Comment: got it thank you. We used to use map and then subscribe to it later on.